# Embedding page in the URL

Tags: browser, uri

Is it possible to have the contents of the file you want to load right in the URL of the browser?
i.e. instead of having "my-domain.com/image.jpg" in the URL, I could just have the data of the image or some static webpage in the URL. 
The files don't need to do anything fancy, just be rendered in the browser.

This would be useful for devices not connected to the internet to display a small HTML page by getting it from a QR code, or for viewing an image from another device in the browser without going through a server.

It's should be safe to assume that all content is very small.

Answer (score 1):

No, the URL is an identifier, a path for data that the browser renders. So it can only contain paths to data, not the data itself.